# Show that this is a topology.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $\Omega$ a family of subsets of $X$. Let's define

$\mathcal{B}_\Omega=\{X\}\cup\{$ finite intersections of elements of $\Omega\}$

and

$T_\Omega=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{$arbitrary unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}_\Omega\}$.

I have to show that $T_\Omega$ is a topology over $X$.
I've got a problem trying to prove the axiom of intersection. I tried this:

Let $A,B\in T_\Omega$. Then $A=\bigcup_{i\in\Lambda} A_i$ and $B=\bigcup_{j\in\Delta} B_j$, with $A_i,B_j\in\mathcal{B}_\Omega$ ($\Lambda$ and $\Delta$ are just sets of indexes).Thus, $A\cap B=\bigcup_{i\in\Lambda} A_i\cap \bigcup_{j\in\Delta} B_j$. I should be able to express this as an arbitrary union of elements of $\mathcal{B}_\Omega$, but I don't know how because I cannot use the usual distribution properties with arbitrary unions.

Comment: "I cannot use the usual distribution properties with arbitrary unions" Why?

Comment: @kennyLau Well, here is always recquired an individual set https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Union_Distributes_over_Intersection 
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_Distributes_over_Union
so I thought it wasn't valid for arbitrary unions

Comment: Wrong page. You should look for [https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_Distributes_over_Union](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_Distributes_over_Union). See the "Family of Sets" part

Answer (score 0):

$$A\cap B=\bigcup_{i\in\Lambda} A_i\cap \bigcup_{j\in\Delta} B_j = \bigcup_{i\in\Lambda,j\in\Delta} A_i \cap B_j$$

Comment: I'm not sure... If you've got the union of a lot of things and another union of another lot of things, it might have non empty intersection, but at the same time if you intersect every set individually they might have empty intersection, implying that the union of all of them is empty.

Comment: The non-empty intersection must come from two original sets, which have non-empty intersection individually

Comment: This is not true in general, look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1993189/144766). Not even for finite unions.

Comment: @mechanodroid that is not what I'm claiming. For a finite case: $(A \cup B) \cap (C \cup D) = (A \cap C) \cup (A \cap D) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (B \cap D)$.

Comment: Ah, you are right, sorry.

Comment: Writing it like this could be clearer:$$A\cap B=\left(\bigcup_{i\in\Lambda} A_i\right)\cap \left(\bigcup_{j\in\Delta} B_j\right)=\bigcup_{i\in\Lambda} \left(A_i\cap \bigcup_{j\in\Delta} B_j\right) = \bigcup_{i\in\Lambda}\bigcup_{j\in\Delta} A_i\cap B_j$$